# Response code for "accept type not supported"

Tags: http

What is the proper response code for a request with an `Accept` header that I don't support?

For example if a request with an `Accept` header `application/json` comes in but the only response types I support are `text/plain` and `text/html`, what response code should I return?

Comment: I think 406 as outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11461327/187606 fits the bill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be HTTP response 406 according the RFC 7231:

> 6.5.6. 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The 406 (Not Acceptable) status code indicates that the target
> resource does not have a current representation that would be
> acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation
> header fields received in the request (Section 5.3), and the server
> is unwilling to supply a default representation.
>
> The server SHOULD generate a payload containing a list of available
> representation characteristics and corresponding resource identifiers
> from which the user or user agent can choose the one most
> appropriate.  A user agent MAY automatically select the most
> appropriate choice from that list.  However, this specification does
> not define any standard for such automatic selection, as described in
> Section 6.4.1.

source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6

Comment: I turned the paragraph into a quote. Can you add a link to the page you are quoting from?

Comment: jeez I was looking at the 5xx codes since it was a server thing.. Thanks!

Comment: (a) it's not a W3C standard, and (b) RFC 2616 is obsolete

Comment: You're right it's obsoleted by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.6 but the information is still valid.