# Is there a proper HTTP status code for unprocessable Content-Type?

Tags: http, status

What is the most correct/meaningful HTTP status code to return when your web server cannot handles the incoming request because it does not understands what the `Content-Type` of the incoming request body is?

Returning straight 400 seems like a bad idea since, according to Wikipedia:

> e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing

And we actually returns 400 when there are parsing errors or similar things for some content types like `application/json` or some of the XML variants.

So is there an HTTP status code to indicate that we don't know how to process the request besides HTTP 400?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP status code for unaccepted Content-Type in request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973813/http-status-code-for-unaccepted-content-type-in-request) and [Appropriate HTTP status code for request specifying invalid Content-Encoding header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461037/appropriate-http-status-code-for-request-specifying-invalid-content-encoding-hea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is the status code you're looking for.

> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.

From [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.16):

> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.