# What http status should I return if client does not follow the rules?

Tags: rest, http

For example, we have an API `POST /test`, which only accept `name: AA` or `name: BB` headers.

If a client send a `name: CC` header, which status code is preferred?

400? 404? 500?

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research. There are literally thousands of questions about _"which status code to return in scenario X"_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most appropriate HTTP status code to return if a required header is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576898/what-is-the-most-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-if-a-required-header-is)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461037/appropriate-http-status-code-for-request-specifying-invalid-content-encoding-hea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050518/what-http-status-response-code-should-i-use-if-the-request-is-missing-a-required, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454811/which-http-status-code-to-use-for-required-parameters-not-provided, https://www.google.com/search?q=http+status+code+for+incorrect+request+headers

Answer (score 0):

If is a permission problem maybe you can send 403 (forbidden). 404 is not found and is not the correct meaning of that and 500 is a server error.